# How to temporarily replace Drupal with static HTML pages?

Tags: theming, routes

I'm a JavaScript dev with no Drupal experience.

I'm working with a church to redesign their Drupal site after their dev moved on without leaving any notes/documentation/etc. In the meantime, I'd like to put up a few static html pages in place of the Drupal site, without getting rid of all the Drupal data.

Can I just "turn off" Drupal, so that routes that are now currently powered by Drupal (ie: `church.org/worship`) will instead render the static file version (ie: `church.org/worship/index.html`)?

Is leveraging Drupal's "maintenance mode" a possible solution? I found this article, https://drupalden.co.uk/static-maintenance-page-replace-drupals-default-maintenance-mode-page, on replacing the default maintenance page, but what about other routes too?

Comment: Simply rename the folder where Drupal currently lives in. And put something else in its place instead. Maybe adjust Drupal's .htaccess file of this Drupal under the different directory still should be accessible to you. Maybe look at https://www.drupal.org/project/tome to generate static HTML from your current site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drupal only kicks in when a file does not exist. So if you create HTML files at the same path where a Drupal page existed, the HTML file will be shown, and Drupal will not be instantiated.

Example: You have a path named /node/4.

If you create a folder in your webroot named 'node', and a file named 4, it will be picked up instead of Drupal being instantiated, even if Drupal exists in the webroot. You may need to do some work to set the headers of the file as text/html though, since there is no file extension on the file to tell the processor that it's an HTML file.